# Does the ng-touch Angular Library Really Only Support Horizontal Swipes and Not Vertical?

Tags: angularjs, touch

That would seem unbelievable and broken to me.  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

Answer (score 5):

It really [doesn't support vertical swipes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch.%24swipe):

> If the horizontal distance is greater, this is a swipe and move and
>   end events follow. - **If the vertical distance is greater, this is a
>   scroll, and we let the browser take over**. A cancel event is sent.

Here's [a module that supports vertical swipe](https://github.com/marmorkuchen-net/angular-swipe).